# Replicating the error when saving down at the end of day

Tags: kdb

I would like to update the table so it has error message at EOD savedown.
The goal is to have different type of data than the assigned type in the same column.

eg.

```
update col:5i from `t where i = 0
```

However,  i got type error. Any idea how I should update the different type of data to those columns?

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to update an existing column? Can it not be a new column so types are consistent?

Comment: it can.  so i tried update test:enlist (`abc;1) from `t  and got a length error

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to deliberately break the consistency of a uniform type column so that it will fail to splay to disk, in order to test your EOD savedown procedures? If so, you can append or pre-append a row like:

```
q)t:([]col:1 2j)
q)show t:(update col:5i from select from t where i = 0),t
col
---
5i
1
2
```

This should then successfully fail to splay :)